# Calculating Total Price Separately for Each User in NestJS TypeORM Query

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a NestJS application with TypeORM, and I'm trying to calculate the total price of items associated with each user. I have a `Pick` entity that is related to `User` and `PickShops` entities. Each `PickShop` record belongs to a single user, and I want to calculate the total price of shops for each user separately.

I've tried using the `getRawMany()` method and modifying the query accordingly, but I'm not getting the expected results. The aggregated total value doesn't seem to be appearing in the results.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
const queryBuilder = this.pick
  .createQueryBuilder('pick')
  .innerJoin('pick.users', 'user')
  .innerJoin('pick.pickShops', 'shops')
  .select(['pick.name', 'SUM(shops.price) AS total'])
  .where('user.id = :userId', { userId: this.request.user.id })
  .groupBy('pick.id');
const result = await queryBuilder.getRawMany();
return result;
```

Result gives me this:

```
[
  {
    "pick_name": "test",
    "total": "10000"
  },
  {
    "pick_name": "test",
    "total": "250000"
  },
  {
    "pick_name": "test",
    "total": "1728232"
  }
]
```

But I want something like this (I know it is so far from my expectation XD)

```
[
  {
    "pick_name": "test",
    "usersShops": [
      {
        "userId": "4",
        "totalPrice": 50000
      },
      {
        "userId": "3",
        "totalPrice": 50000
      }
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

My models:

Pick model:

```
@Entity({ name: 'pick' })
export class Pick extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 200 })
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.picks, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
  users: User[];

  @OneToMany(() => PickShops, (pickShop) => pickShop.pick, { cascade: true })
  pickShops: PickShops[];
}
```

PickShops model:

```
@Entity({ name: 'pickShops' })
export class PickShops extends BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 200, nullable: false })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'bigint', nullable: false })
  price: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.pickShops)
  user: User;

  @ManyToOne(() => Pick, (pick) => pick.pickShops)
  pick: Pick;
}
```

Could someone please guide me on the correct way to structure the query and group the results so that I can calculate the total price separately for each user in each pick? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!